# MongoDB Beginner Error loading js file

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB, and I am teaching myself from scratch.

I am trying to run js file through MongoDB via a CMD

the js file has the following statements.

```
print ("Hostname:");
print ("\t"+hostname());
print ("Date:");
print ("\t"+Date());
db = connect ("localhost/admin");
print ("Admin Collections:");
printjson (db.getcollectionNames());
```

but when I try the following to run the file.

```
mongo shell_script.js
```

I get the following error,

```
[thread1] syntaxError: missing ; before statement :@(shell):1:1
```

Can someone point me in the right direction please.

Regards Rob

Comment: Your JS is correct (although getcollectionNames should be getCollectionNames). I've tested it and it worked. What is the OS and Mongodb version you're running?

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked

Comment: was it just the method's name? I've added an answer to your question, can you please accept it so we close this matter?

Answer (score 0):

On your code, `getcollectionNames` should be `getCollectionNames`